# Book where a Prehistoric Hidden Meadow is Found by Two Teenaged Boys In France

Tags: story-identification, novel

I read this book in the late 70s, not sure when it was published.

One summer, two boys find a pristine meadow that can only be found through a narrow passageway. They first are drawn by pictographs and early art and painting on what begins as a cave/passage wall.  Once on the other side that can only be accessed through the passage they meet a Cro-Magnon Man and they begin to visit him daily.  At the end of the summer they are to big to fit through the passage and  have lost access to the Meadow and their friend forever.  Oddly enough the meadow can't be found when looking for it via surrounding areas.

The time period is mid 20th century I believe, set in the French countryside.

Comment: I read this book in the late 70's not sure when it was published the time period is mid 20th century I believe, set in the French country side.

Comment: _At the end of the summer they are too big to fit through the passage..._ Really?) They both got fat in just a summer?

Comment: The author said their shoulders were too broad and they could no longer crawl through the narrowest section. LOL  It's  really good story.